# PCで再生中の動画の音声認識

Tags: windows, c++

Windowsの音声認識については以下の連載で説明があり、なんとかやればできそうだと思うのですが
、マイクではなくＰＣで再生中の音を入力にしたい場合はどうすれば良いでしょうか？

[連載：Intel Perceptual Computing SDK入門（5）PerC SDKを利用して開発する方法](http://www.buildinsider.net/small/perc/05)

googleの音声認識等の方が設定が簡単なのであれば、そちらでもよいかなと考えています。

Comment: リンク先の記事の要約 (何を使って音声認識しているのか) を含めると、回答者の助けと時間の節約になると思います。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows のサウンドカードドライバには、大抵 Stereo Mix (or ステレオミキサー)が含まれていることがありますので、そのデバイスを入力として使うことで、サウンド出力と、マイク入力をつなげられます。この種のデバイスはデフォルト非表示になっていることが多いので、以下の 1~2 の手順で有効化してください。

#### 1. 録音デバイス一覧から「無効なデバイスの表示」

*サウンド > 録音デバイス を右クリックから 「無効なデバイスの表示」を選択*
[image: 無効な入力デバイスの表示]

#### 2. ステレオミキサーを有効化する

*録音デバイスのステレオミキサーを右クリックから「有効」を選択*
[image: 入力デバイスの有効化]

*入力レベルがゼロになっていないかは確かめる*
[image: ステレオミキサーのボリューム]

#### 3. テスト: Youtube から、Google 音声検索

精度の問題から、実用性は全くありませんが、例えば、再生音声の一部をGoogleに食わせるには、以下のように、Chrome で Google.com を表示し、音声入力デバイス設定をステレオミキサーにしてから、メディアの再生を行います。

*Google Chrome: google.com のアドレスバー*
[image: Chrome: Google.com のアドレスバーから、音声入力デバイスの選択]

*ブラウザ内で音声出力／入力が行われる様子*
[image: ブラウザの出力をそのまま、音声検索の入力とする]

#### 補足

デバイスがみつからないなどのことであれば、3.5 ミニプラグを買うのが早い気もします。

[image: 3.5 ミニプラグ オスオス]